# Datetime in C# add days

Tags: c#, date, c#-4.0, datetime, addition

I want to add days in some date. I have a code like this:

```
DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtStartDate.Text); 
Int64 addedDays = Convert.ToInt64(txtDaysSupp.Text); 
endDate.AddDays(addedDays); 
DateTime end = endDate; 
this.txtEndDate.Text = end.ToShortDateString();
```

But this code is not working, days are not added! What the stupid mistake I'm doing?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

DateTime is immutable.  That means you cannot change it's state and have to assign the result of an operation to a variable.

```
endDate = endDate.AddDays(addedDays);
```

Answer (score 22):

You need to catch the return value.

The [DateTime.AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) method returns an object who's value is the sum of the date and time of the instance and the added value.

```
endDate = endDate.AddDays(addedDays);
```

Comment: moderator note: this is _not_ a duplicated answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/15359961/6451573: check the post dates;

Answer (score 12):

Its because the `AddDays()` method returns a new `DateTime`, that you are not assigning or using anywhere.

Example of use:

```
DateTime newDate = endDate.AddDays(2);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can add days to a date like this:

```
// add days to current **DateTime**
var addedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);

// add days to current **Date**
var addedDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(10);

// add days to any DateTime variable
var addedDateTime = anyDate.AddDay(10);
```

Answer (score 7):

Assign the enddate to some date variable because `AddDays` method returns new Datetime as the result..

```
Datetime somedate=endDate.AddDays(2);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
DateTime dateTime =  DateTime.Now;
DateTime? newDateTime = null;
TimeSpan numberOfDays = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0, 0, 0);
newDateTime = dateTime.Add(numberOfDays);
```

Answer (score 4):

Why do you use `Int64`? `AddDays` demands a `double`-value to be added. Then you'll need to use the return-value of `AddDays.` See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx).