# Auto increment datetime

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

It is possible to auto-increment datetime which I parse from [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) to add `AddDays(7)` and then insert it to DB?

```
string strValue = Page.Request.Form["daterange"];
string strValue2 = Page.Request.Form["daterange2"];

DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse(strValue);
DateTime myDate2 = DateTime.Parse(strValue2);

queryStr = "INSERT INTO `wp_reservations` ( `arrival`, `departure`, `user`, `name`, `email`, `country`, `approve`, `room`, `roomnumber`, `number`, `childs`, `price`, `custom`, `customp`, `reservated`) VALUES ('" + strValue + "INTERVAL 7 DAY', '" + strValue2 + "', 0, '" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "', '" + emailValue + "', 'SI', '" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + "', '" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "', '1', 10, 0, '0;0', '', '', '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt") + "');";
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: It's strange how you use the exact function syntax in your question... `myDate = myDate.AddDays(7);`

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand either...

Comment: It's very strange, indeed.

Comment: DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt");

Comment: ...I suppose you also need to look at using the correct value in your query string, and you also need to research SQL injection and how to use SQL parameters

Comment: @musefan Yeah i'm gonna use SQL parameters. Anyway i find solution for my problem.

Comment: string test = DateTime.Parse(strValue).AddDays(7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt");

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)` in insert query

Answer (score 0):

If u want to do this in code see [Datetime in C# add days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359887/datetime-in-c-sharp-add-days)

U can also do it in DAO query see [DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)