# Displaying value of a date control depending on another date control

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker

I have two controls in my application. The first one displays the current date and the second one displays the `+7` days from the current date and which is also readonly.

My Problem is when I change the date of the first date control, the second one should show the +7 days from the selected date. I am not able to perform this.

I am trying this below statement:

```
dtcToDate.Value=(dtcFromDate.DateValue)+7;
```

Comment: You need to use the [AddDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Please specify with tags in your question what technology is used in your application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359887/datetime-in-c-sharp-add-days

Answer (score 0):

Use the *AddDays()* method.

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime newDate = currentDate.AddDays(7);
```