# C# SSIS Transform Add Days to Date

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a transformation script I am running in C# within SSIS. I am simply attempting to take a date attribute from my source file and add a single day to that date. Do I really need to create a variable to facilitate this?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, can you please include the code you've already tried and this would also provide better context for your question.

Comment: It is up to you how to code ie  attribute date can be incremented date++ or  x= var+1 and use ..

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to perform the task of adding a day to a date attribute in C# script, then take a look at the following link:

[Datetime in C# add days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359887/datetime-in-c-sharp-add-days)

Otherwise, an expression like the following applied in a derived column under data flow will also work.

```
DATEADD("day", 1, DateAttribute) //Apply if Attribute already is in datetime type.
DATEADD("day", 1, (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)DateAttribute) //Apply if Attribute needs to be converted to datetime type in order to then add a day.
```

Whether or not you need to add a variable is something I cannot answer.  More information on how this attribute is applied downstream in the pipeline is required.  Using variables is generally a good practice in SSIS packages.  Take a look at the following very helpful link for best practices.

[Best Practices](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2012/01/29/suggested-best-practises-and-naming-conventions.aspx)

Hope this helps.